# array count returned from NSFetchRequest is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm using Core Data to cache data, here is my code to insert object:

```
//data array count is 15
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dataArray)
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CacheData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title LIKE '%@'",dictionary[@"title"]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *fetchArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];

    if ([fetchArray count] == 0)
    {
        CacheData *cacheData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CacheData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [cacheData setTitle:dictionary[@"title"]];
        [cacheData setLink:dictionary[@"link"]];
        [cacheData setPublishDate:dictionary[@"pubDate"]];

        NSError *insertError = nil;
        if (![context save:&insertError])
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
}
```

The count of `dataArray` is 15, so I should insert 15 items to Core Data.
But once I used `NSFetchRequest` to fetch items, the array count returned added 1, and become 16, and fetch items again, it added 1 to 17 again:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CacheData" inManagedObjectContext:[[CacheDataManagement sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchArray = [[[CacheDataManagement sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
for (CacheData *data in fetchArray) {
    NSLog(@"fetch:%@",[data title]);
}

NSLog(@"%ld",[fetchArray count]);  //fetch array count is 16
```

Something wrong with my code ?

**Update**

Changed `if ([fetchArray count] != 0) { … }` to `if ([fetchArray count] == 0) { … }`

Comment: Isn't dataArray the list of 15 dictionaries each with a particular title? fetchArray seems to be completely unrelated to dataArray except that the current dictionary gets inserted into cache

Comment: Before inserting data into cache, I use fetchArray to check if the inserting data is already exists.

Comment: then it seems like you should be checking that fetchArray == 0 instead

Comment: sorry ,this is a mistake, but the return count is still wrong.

Comment: what is the return count after your correction? also did you clear the cache, it probably has duplicates

Comment: the count I insert is 15, but once I use NSFetchRequest, the count plus 1, and the pulsed object is null, not duplicates.

Comment: What 'title' are you seeing with  `NSLog(@"fetch:%@",[data title])` ? Are there any duplicate ?

Comment: I would also put a logging within the context save failure.

Comment: The return statement is not good in a for loop. Are you sure you are not getting any error?

Comment: In addition. Your code has performance issues. The fetch should be executed before the loop, the same should apply to the saving.

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem it's not quite clear to me (I would like to have more details), I'll try to give you some hints.

First, the `save` should be done outside the `for` loop (In addition it's not correct to do a `return` within it).

```
// for in loop here    

NSError *insertError = nil;
if (![context save:&insertError]) {
    NSLog("%@", insertError);
    return NO; // do it if the method you are running in returns a bool
}
```

Second, to check for duplicated you should rely on a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) but if don't have it the predicate should look like the following.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@",dictionary[@"title"]];
```

Third, also the execute for `executeFetchRequest:error:` should be replace with `countForFetchRequest:error:` since you don't need to return the objects but only a count. According to Apple doc, it

> Returns the number of objects a given fetch request would have
>   returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:.

Finally, in the `for` loop you are executing a request each time. My suggestion is to move execute a request before the loop and then checking for results within it. This according to [Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1). In this case, the pattern will enforce you to have a GUID for you entity.

Obviously, these are just hints. The real way to find the problem is to debug. In addition, I will perform tests starting from a fresh environment, i.e. the app has been deleted from the simulator or device.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `[fetchArray count] != 0` checks the inserting data is already exists. Try changing it like

```
if ([fetchArray count] == 0)
{
     CacheData *cacheData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CacheData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
     [cacheData setTitle:dictionary[@"title"]];
     [cacheData setLink:dictionary[@"link"]];
     [cacheData setPublishDate:dictionary[@"pubDate"]];

     NSError *insertError = nil;
     if (![context save:&insertError])
     {
         return NO;
     }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code , but the return count is still not the same